# How to access private variables in fortran modules?

Tags: fortran

I know the idea of private variables is that they shouldn't be accessed, and I do want it to work this way when using the module in the rest of the program, but I need it for the purpose of checking the internal workings of the module.

Say I have the following simplified example:

```
module mod
  implicit none
  private
  integer :: value
  public :: set_value

contains

subroutine set_value(input)
  implicit none
  integer,intent(in) :: input
  value=input
end subroutine

end module
```

And I now want to test the subroutine to see if it is actually doing what I want: I would like to write a program that uses the module, calls the routine `set_value` with input 8 and then checks if the internal variable `value` is now 8.

Can I do this? Or is it there another way to unit test initializers of private variables?

Comment: write a `get_value` function and use that to test.

Comment: Even if I would only use that function for the purpose of testing? Also, wouldn't I be testing both routines at once then?

Comment: If you do not want to follow @casey, simply set it public for the purpose of testing, and set it back to private after that!

Answer (score 7):

You have three approaches as I see them.

1. write a get function to get the value and test.  You indicate in the comments that this is sub-optimal though, so..
2. If you have a compiler with Fortran 2003 support (e.g. any recent version of a modern Fortran compiler), declare the variable with the `protected` attribute instead of the `private` attribute.  This will allow your variable to be read from any code, but not modified.  This will enforce that it can only be set via your setter function but you can inspect its value directly in your unit test.

   ```
   integer, protected :: value
   ```
3. Lastly, if all else fails, you can conditionally compile the module so that sometimes the variable is not private.  For example, do this:

   ```
   module mod
     implicit none
     private
     integer :: value
     public :: set_value

   #ifdef UNITTESTING
     public :: value
   #endif

   contains
   ...
   end module
   ```

   Then change the filename from `.f90` to `.F90` so that it will be pre-processed (at least on gfortran and ifort).  When you compile it normally, `value` will be private, but if you instead compile with the flag `-DUNITTESTING` then `value` will be public.  When you compile your test cases, you use that flag and they can now inspect the variable directly.

Comment: Please, not conditional compilation ... An alternative might be protected, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020460/protected-global-variables-in-fortran

Comment: @IanBush thanks, I'd forgotten about that.  I've added that but kept the conditional compile part as a fallback on the off chance they are using an ancient compiler.

Comment: Excellent! But I won't remove the comment as conditional compilation is EVIL!!!!!! (Sits back, awaits the comments)(But I honestly think this, it's just an even worse form of global variable)

Comment: What about testing private functions and subroutines? I disagree with @IanBush about conticional compilation, for me it's the least intrussive solution. Some of us are stuck with Fortran 90...